# Hierarchical Data Grid Child

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, telerik, hierarchicaldatatemplate

```
<telerik:RadGridView x:Name="rgvData" CanUserFreezeColumns="False" GridLinesVisibility="Horizontal" IsReadOnly="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                         telerik:Theming.Theme="Office_Blue" ItemsSource="{Binding}" >
        <telerik:RadGridView.ChildTableDefinitions>
            <telerik:GridViewTableDefinition />
        </telerik:RadGridView.ChildTableDefinitions>
        <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding StudentID}" Header="Category ID" />
            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding StudentFN}" Header="Category Name" />
            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding StudentLN}" Header="Description" />
            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding Picture}" Header="Picture" />
        </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
        <telerik:RadGridView.HierarchyChildTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <telerik:RadGridView x:Name="RadGridView1" Loaded="rgvData_Loaded" ShowInsertRow="True"  CanUserInsertRows="True"  ItemsSource="{Binding Subjects}" CanUserFreezeColumns="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowGroupPanel="False" IsReadOnly="False">
                    <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
                        <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding SubjectID}" Header="Order ID" />
                        <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding SubjectName}" Header="Employee ID" />
                        <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding SubjectProfessor}" Header="Order Date" />
                        <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding ShipCountry}" Header="Ship Country" />
                    </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
                </telerik:RadGridView>
            </DataTemplate>
        </telerik:RadGridView.HierarchyChildTemplate>
    </telerik:RadGridView>
```

MainXaml.Cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    DataAccessDataContext m_dcData;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainWindow_Loaded);
        this.rgvData.Items.CollectionChanged += new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(Items_CollectionChanged);
        rgvData.Filtered += new EventHandler<Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridView.GridViewFilteredEventArgs>(rgvData_Filtered);
    }

    void rgvData_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var childGrid = (RadGridView)sender;
    var parentRow = childGrid.ParentRow;

    if (parentRow != null)
    {
        rgvData.SelectedItem = childGrid.DataContext;
        parentRow.IsExpandedChanged += new RoutedEventHandler(parentRow_IsExpandedChanged);
    }
     }

void parentRow_IsExpandedChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    rgvData.SelectedItem = ((GridViewRow)sender).DataContext;
}x


    void rgvData_Filtered(object sender, Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridView.GridViewFilteredEventArgs e)
    {
        DataContext = m_dcData;
        m_dcData = new DataAccessDataContext();
        m_dcData.Log = Console.Out;
        rgvData.ItemsSource = m_dcData.Students;
        rgvData.ShowInsertRow = true;
    }

    private void Items_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
            {
                foreach (Student item in e.NewItems)
                {
                    m_dcData.Students.InsertOnSubmit(item);
                }
            }
            if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove)
            {
                foreach (Student item in e.OldItems)
                {
                    m_dcData.Students.DeleteOnSubmit(item);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception s)
        { }
    }
    void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        m_dcData = new DataAccessDataContext();
        m_dcData.Log = Console.Out;
        rgvData.ItemsSource = m_dcData.Students;
        rgvData.ShowInsertRow = true;

        rgvData.ItemsSource = m_dcData.Students;
        rgvData.ShowInsertRow = true;
    }
}
```

Hi I have no problem on loading the child data related to its parent source. The problem is that if I try to expand another row it loads the first data for it. Example is if I have row1 expanded it displays the correct child table but if I go to row2 and expand it, its child records are for row1. I tried looking for the answer and putting the parent_IsExpandedChanged event to handle it but still it wont display the correct data. If I try to reload the application again and try to expand row 2 or row 3. its child is correct but if i expanded another row it will display the child for row 2 or row 3. Please help what am i doing wrong

Comment: im using linq to sql class in getting the data from sql

Comment: It looks like ur problem is because of the grid...try using the forums in telerik(http://www.telerik.com/community/forums.aspx)..they are quite quick to respond...Also add the tag 'telerik' to your question...it makes it easy to identify

Comment: Hi. if you get loaded, you needn't work with loaded event. for eager load data you can try RowIsExpandedChanging event on root grid. Use ObservableCollection for your child items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XAML looks sound, and I can't see that the code you posted would cause a problem.  Have you confirmed that the data loaded is correct?  You might actually be loading the same subject data for each student.
You can easily check by putting this code into a button click event on your window:

```
IEnumerable<Student> list = (IEnumerable<Student>)this.DataContext;
foreach(Student stu in Students)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(stu.StudentID + ":");
    foreach(Subject sub in stu.Subjects)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("\\t" + sub.SubjectID)
    }
}
```